Необычный аккордеон на js
Всем привет. Столкнулся впервые с таким фильтром. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными аккордеонами?Пол дня сижу ломаю голову, не могу придумать как правильно его сверстать? Я сделал такую верстку, но что-то не то. Помогите пожалуйста.
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
      <div class="accordion-header" id="accordionHeader1">
          <button class="accordion-button" aria-expanded="false">
              Верхняя одежда
              <img src="./img/icons/Icon_arrow-down.svg" class="accordion-arrow">
          </button>
          
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-content" aria-labelledby="accordionHeader1">
          <div class="categories">
              <button class="category">Жилетки</button>
              <button class="category">Пальто</button>
              <button class="category">Бомбер</button>
              <button class="category">Кожанын куртки</button>
              <button class="category">Пуховики</button>
              <button class="category">Тонкие куртки и ветровки</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Додайте інші акордеони за потреби тут -->
</div>



Аккордеон с обычными элементами внутри блока...что тут необычного то

А как правильно сделать, чтоб при закрытом аккордеоне , список фильтров все равно отображался ? Меня собственно это и сбило с толку))

При закрытом аккордеоне список фильтров НЕ должен отображаться. Это нонсенс. Это как сказать: как нажать кнопку в положение "выкл", но чтоб свет остался включенным

@АлексейШиманский, вероятно, он имеет в виду, что при закрытом аккордеоне фильтр всё равно должен применяться. Если у него функция фильтрации завязана на dom-дерево, то в этом могут возникнуть сложности.

@Qwertiy ааа. ну да, может быть.... и да, ты прав, реализация в этом случае не оч....хотя не совсем понятно почему оно должно не работать))

@Qwertiy, немного не то имел ввиду) Заказчик говорит, что фильтр должен отображаться при скрытом аккордеоне но с возможностью свайпа вправо. А вот если открыть акордеон , то эти фильтра должны отображаться уже внутри , как положено. Возможно есть идеи как правильно реализовать?

Ребят, сделал вот такой вариант. Вроде похоже на то , что от меня требовалось. Единственное, немного подправлю верстку, стили и  доделаю js, чтобы можно было выбрать несколько категорий из фильтров.


document.getElementById('accordionHeaderCustom').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const arrowIcon = document.querySelector('.arrow-icon-custom');
  const categoriesContainer = document.getElementById('categoriesContainerCustom');

  if (categoriesContainer.classList.contains('open')) {
    categoriesContainer.classList.remove('open');
    arrowIcon.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
    categoriesContainer.classList.add('open');
    arrowIcon.classList.add('open');
  }
});
.right-shop-filters-modal .accordion-custom {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .accordion-header-custom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .accordion-content-custom {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .arrow-icon-custom {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .arrow-icon-custom.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .categories-container-custom {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .categories-container-custom.open {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.right-shop-filters-modal .category-custom {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
<div class="accordion-custom">
  <div class="accordion-header-custom" id="accordionHeaderCustom">
    <span>Верхняя одежда</span>
    <img src="./img/icons/Icon_arrow-down.svg" alt="Arrow icon" class="arrow-icon-custom">
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content-custom">
    <div class="categories-container-custom" id="categoriesContainerCustom">
      <div class="category-custom">Жилетки</div>
      <div class="category-custom">Пальто</div>
      <div class="category-custom">Бомбер</div>
      <div class="category-custom">Кожанын куртки</div>
      <div class="category-custom">Пуховики</div>
      <div class="category-custom">Тонкие куртки и ветровки</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





А как правильно сделать, чтоб при закрытом аккордеоне , список фильтров все равно отображался?

хм... если, [как я предполагаю], речь о выбранных фильтрах... я бы сделал как то так:


.cat:not(:checked) ~ *:not(:checked) + *{display: none}
.cat:not(:checked) + b:after{content: 'выбрано:'; float: right;}
.x > *{margin: .5em;}
.cat + b{grid-column: span 4}
.cat:checked ~ *:nth-child(even){grid-column: span 4}

.x{
  display: grid;
  margin: 1em;
  background: pink;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
<div class='x'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='cat' name='cat1'/><b>cat1 name V</b>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f1'/><i>f1 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f2' checked/><i>f2 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f3'/><i>f3 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f4' checked/><i>f4 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f5'/><i>f5 name</i>
</div>

<div class='x'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='cat' name='cat2'/><b>cat2 name V</b>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f1' checked/><i>f1 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f2'/><i>f2 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f3' checked/><i>f3 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f4'/><i>f4 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f5'/><i>f5 name</i>
</div>

<div class='x'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='cat' name='cat3'/><b>cat3 name V</b>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f1'/><i>f1 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f2' checked/><i>f2 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f3' checked/><i>f3 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f4' checked/><i>f4 name</i>
  <input type='checkbox' name='f5'/><i>f5 name</i>
</div>



не идеально конечно, но на ff 91 вполне работает. осталось только раскрасить по вкусу.
p.s. no one letter js code

немного не то имел ввиду) Заказчик говорит, что фильтр должен отображаться при скрытом аккордеоне но с возможностью свайпа вправо. А вот если открыть акордеон , то эти фильтра должны отображаться уже внутри , как положено. Возможно есть идеи как правильно реализовать?

@ДмитрийСердюк, типа уведомлений на экране блокировки? А вот если открыть аккордеон , то эти фильтра должны отображаться уже внутри , как положено стало быть, до - снаружи него. свайп-ивент фильтрам, display: contents аккордеонам и display: grid их родителю. как то так...

Вроде получилось. Сейчас покажу, что вышло и что от меня требовалось)
